# Thread in servlet

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

In an application if there are multiple servlets involved then is everytime a new thread is created for a different servlet

for ex i have 2 servlets servlet 1 and servlet 2 both are getting rquest from the same html form one is getting through anchor tag and another through form

when link is clicked request is sent to servlet one which dispatches request to index page again and from there the form is submitted where request is sent to servlet 2

so are 2 threads created each for servlet 1 and servlet 2 or only 1 thread is created which serves both servlets ??

Answer (score 6):

The general pattern for a Servlet container is to use one `Thread` to handle one request.

> for ex i have 2 servlets servlet 1 and servlet 2 both are getting
>   rquest from the same html form one is getting through anchor tag and
>   another through form

When you submit the `form`, the browser sends an HTTP request. Your server dispatches a `Thread` to handle it. Think of it doing something like this (it's much more complex in reality)

```
final Servlet servlet = ...// which servlet is url-mapped to the request
Runnable toRun = new Runnable(
    public void run() {
        servlet.service(request, response); // with exception handling of course
    }
);
Thread toDispatch = new Thread(toRun); // actually get it from pool, but for simplicity
toDispatch.start();
```

Again, if you follow an anchor link, your browser sends a new HTTP request that gets handled the same way.

The `Servlet` class instance is shared among threads.

Comment: @Sotirious thanks for your reply actually i built the programme using eclipse ide and i displayed thread name on both the servlets and it is giving the same value.Does that mean one thread is created for one session and it is used to serve all the servlets involved in a particular session??

Comment: @anubhav That's because the Servlet container is using a `Thread` pool. When a request comes in, a `Thread` is acquired from the pool to handle it. When the request is finished and a response is sent back, the `Thread` is returned to the pool and is available for future requests. It has nothing to do with the http session and doesn't matter which `Servlet` is involved.

Comment: so it means there is a possibility that same thread would be used to serve another servlet?? but for all the servlets there will be one session for a request  so that one could make use of one session attribute set in one servlet in another servlet.

Comment: @anubhav For each request, the container will create `HttpServletRequest` (which might be bound to an `HttpSession` object) and `HttpServletResponse` objects. These are given to the servlet that is being used in the handling `Thread`. This is abstracted away from you. You generally only need to care about your servlet. The `Thread` instance can be used to handle any request with any servlet.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your help and clearing my doubts i would like to know whether my above comment so it means there is a possibility that same thread would be used to serve another servlet?? but for all the servlets there will be one session for a request so that one could make use of one session attribute set in one servlet in another servlet is correct or not.Thanks !!!

Comment: @anubhav The same `Thread` **object** can be used in another request or within the same request (with `forward`, `include`) to handle any amount of different request, regardless of the corresponding `Servlet`. There is at most one `HttpSession` object related to an `HttpServletRequest`. You can use it to set session attributes as you wish. The **session** attributes don't care about which `Servlet` is being used to handle the request, they are available to the **session**.

Comment: @anubhav You're welcome. When you are satisfied, consider accepting one of the answers below that helped.

Answer (score 3):

When a request arrived at Servlet Container (Eg: Tomcat, WAS), it usually picks up a thread randomly from ThreadPool and that received request will be processed by the chosen thread for entire request life cycle. In other words the same thread is executed from UI layer to Service layer to Data layer. And there is no guarantee that the same thread is assigned in the subsequent requests even if you click the same link which in turn submits the request to the same servlet. Being said that there are chances that the same thread will be picked up by Container in the immediate request.

If you want to test, print thread names in a Servlet and submit the request multiple times. In your example, click on the anchor link multiple times and see the result.

**Answer to your question:**
As a said above, first of all a new thread will not be created each time when a request arrived. There may be chance that the same thread will be used by Servlet2.

Comment: actually i built the programme using eclipse ide and i displayed thread name on both the servlets and it is giving the same value.Does that mean one thread is created for one session and it is used to serve all the servlets involved in a particular session??

Comment: Nope! You might also want to try putting thread to sleep for some time and submit a new request from another window before the previous request(or thread) wakes up. BTW, Which application server you are using?

Answer (score 1):

Every request to web server is served by a new thread from thread pool. And servlet instances are shared across the requests i.e. thread. So good design practice is not have global variable in servlet else will see race condition.

Comment: thanks for ur reply , servlet is loaded based on load on startup value in web.xml and instantiated after that but if its not provided then its loaded and instantiated when it receives first request and init method is executed only once for its initalization.One should not have global varibale like session or request data as servlet instance since it will be shared by all thread.For every new request a new thread is created.I am asking what will happen in the case which i have described above.

Comment: for your case it's a new request so it will be handled by a thread. But we should not bother about that.

Answer (score 0):

1. each http request is handled in a separate  thread and as creating thread adds some overhead so servers maintain a thread pool and when a request comes in they just reuse a free thread to serve that request.
2. if you create a session in one servlet and set a session attribute then for that session that session attribute can be accessed in any other servlet.